# Smoth scrolling to an anchor upon clicking on a button class

Tags: html, jquery, elementor

I am trying to generate a jQuery code that will allow me to scroll to the anchor #form everytime a user clicks on a class .elementor-button pafe-form-builder-button elementor-size-sm

```
    $(".elementor-button pafe-form-builder-button elementor-size-sm").click(function(){

    var mainOffset = $("#form").offset().top;


        if ( $(document).scrollTop() > mainOffset ) {
                $(document).scrollTop( $("#brownRegion").offset().top );

        }
        else{

        }
});
```

I have implemented the code [here](https://rozi.lavaneruim.co.il/) and added an anchor but it doesn't seem to work. I want the user to be scrolled above the form field upon clicking on any button. What should I change in my code?

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. Please also read: [Can I just link to my website?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: why not just use an anchor instead of a button to scroll down to an anchor with an ID and use the default `scroll-behavior: smooth`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without using JQuery :

```
document.getElementById('your-target-element').scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
```